# swift json how to fill an object

Tags: json, swift

here is my issue, I would like to create a function with this prototype :

```
func doPostRequest(......)->JSON()
```

And I write it like that :

```
func downloadData(completed:@escaping()->()){
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        response in
        let result = response.result

        if let dict = ... {

            self._temp = String(format: "%.0f °C", temp - 273.15)
            ...
        }

        completed()
    })
}
```

I'd like to return an Any object or dictionary, something with my JSON in... but each time I try to implement return I have a nil object ! Maybe a scope problem how can I implement this function to have

```
var myJson:NSDictionary
myJson=downloadData(......) ???
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why not use SwiftyJSON?

Answer (score 0):

Since the method in the body works asynchronously you have to declare your request method with an completion handler for example

```
func doPostRequest(completion: @escaping ([String:Any])->())
```

On return it passes a Swift dictionary.

The method can be used with this code:

```
var myJson = [String:Any]()

...

doPostRequest() { json in 
  self.myJson = json
  // do something with the returned data
}
```

Comment: i implemented like that

Comment: Your code doesn't imply anything which could return `nil`. Edit your question, add the relevant code and describe more in detail what is returned where and what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to create a [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper) to map your objects and use [AlamofireObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper) to get 
 try this code

```
request(url, method: .post, parameters:params).validate().responseObject{(response:
        DataResponse<objectMapperclass>)in

        switch response.result{

        case.success(let data): 
        let objects = data 

        case.faliure(_): 
   }
}
```

Comment: you can get tutorials from the links that i had given